# How does a Timer work in Swift?

Tags: swift, timer, selector

I am using a Timer in Swift and unsure of how it exactly works. I am trying to scan for 2 seconds, connect to a peripheral device, and then end scanning. I have the following code where `connectToPeripheral` , `startScan`, and `endScan` are functions in the same class.

```
    startScan()
Timer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(connectToPeripheral), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    endScan()
```

How does the selector work in the timer? After the timer is called by the code, does the code only execute the selector and not call on whatever bit of code comes next or does it call on what comes next only after the selector finishes running? Basically, I'm asking what is the event cycle concerning Timers and its selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Timer` calls the method specified in its selector input argument after the time elapsed specified as the `timeInterval`. The `Timer` doesn't effect the life cycle of the rest of the code (except for the method specified in the selector of course), every other function is executed as normal.

See this minimal Playground example:

```
class TimerTest: NSObject {
    
    var timer:Timer?
    
    func scheduleTimer(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(TimerTest.timerCall), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    func timerCall(){
        print("Timer executed")
    }
}

print("Code started")
TimerTest().scheduleTimer(2)
print("Execution continues as normal")

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Output:

> print("Code started")
>
> TimerTest().scheduleTimer(2)
>
> print("Execution continues as normal")